# Proximity analysis of posted speed limit

Tags: proximity, here-maps

I want to perform a proximity search around my current position (moving vehicle) to find the links on the roads that have unique posted speed limits associated. I am imagining a big circular region with, say 1 mile radius, around my location as the center, and I want to request the static speed limit for each link or a segment of the road.

Right now i am using the rest-api query method to find out the speed limit at my current location on a given link.However, I want to know the speed limit of the connecting road, if I take the next exit.

The closest match to what i am trying to achieve is on this link: (https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/platform-data/topics/resource-search-proximity.html). Has anyone tried this method before?

A solution is given at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679799/here-maps-api-speed-limit-with-multiple-waypoints) where it is advised to use tiles and layers concept.

UPDATE: After some research, i figured out that indeed using tile method is the way to go. Additionally, knowing what HERE maps layers contain is fundamental to designing the algorithm. I found this link really helpful (https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/platform-data/topics/example-layers.html).

It is indeed a very interesting puzzle, to know what each layer has to offer and then try querying for the right attributes from a specific layer based on the "functional class" of your choice.

Comment: The tile-based approach appears to be what Here are pushing people to use now, as in your second link. It means more preprocessing, but once you have built an appropriate network topology, you should be able to look up links directly within some radius. You haven't mentioned technology choices, but Postgres/Postgis is certainly one possibility.

Comment: It seems that the tiles are fixed in their sizes, and when you give a coordinate to calculate the tile at a zoom level, you could be at the corner of the tile just about to travel out of that tile boundary. How do we make sure we, say, query a tile size with the coordinate in the middle to make the geo boundary the most relevant?